# Windows doesn't have a user with Administrator privilege

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator

I had only one user account in my computer, and it had Administrator privilege. I changed its privilege to **Guest** using `control userpasswords2` command in RUN windows yesterday.

Now I have only one account on my computer and its privilege of guest! 
What shall I do?

When I want to run `control userpasswords2` again, one pop-up windows appear that ask for the Administrator password to run this program, but because of not having administrator account on system the field to enter the password is disabled.

Comment: Enable the default built-in `Administrator` account

Comment: If you [start Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-computer-safe-mode#start-computer-safe-mode=windows-7) you should be able to log on with the built-in Administrator account, which by default has no password. From there you can revert the changes you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Lost administrator account on Windows 7

> Like Vista, the Windows 7 built-in Administrator account is disabled by default. However, when there are no other administrative accounts on the system the built-in Administrator account may become enabled. Go into Safe Mode and see if Administrator appears on the Welcome Screen. If it does, log in and create an extra administrative account for elevation and emergencies (see below for suggested user account setup).
>
> If Administrator doesn't appear on the Welcome Screen, enable it as
>   follows:
>
> If you have a Windows 7 installation DVD (not a recovery DVD) you can
>   boot the system with it. Select the default language, then choose
>   "Repair your computer". Then select "Command Prompt". At the command
>   prompt type:
>
> ```
> net user administrator /active:yes [enter]
> ```
>
> Remove the DVD, reboot the computer, and log into the built-in
>   Administrator account.
>
> If you don't have a Windows 7 installation DVD (only have a recovery disc), the computer mftr. may have given you the Windows 7 System Repair option (not a System Recovery!) on the diagnostic menu. This diagnostic menu is the same one where you can choose Safe Mode. To get to this menu, repeatedly tap the F8 key as the computer is starting up. Or you can make a bootable Repair DVD from the file at this link:
>
> http://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/
>
> Note: All the Neosmart recovery disc downloads are torrent files.
>   There is a good explanation of torrent files at the Neosmart website.
>   You will need a torrent client such as muTorrent to get the files. The
>   torrent client will download the .iso file with which to create the
>   bootable DVD.
>
> After you have created the extra administrative user account log into it and disable the built-in Administrator again for security purposes:
>
> Start Orb>Search box>type: cmd When cmd appears in Results above,
>   right-click it and choose "Run as administrator" [OK]. Now you will
>   get the command prompt. At the command prompt type:
>
> ```
> net user administrator /active:no [enter]
> ```
>
> Exit the command prompt.
>
> General Recommendations For Setting Up Users In Windows 7:
>
> You absolutely do not want to have only one user account. Like XP, Vista and all other modern operating systems, Windows 7 is a multi-user operating system with built-in system accounts such as Administrator, Default, All Users, and Guest. These accounts should be left alone as they are part of the operating system structure.
>
> You particularly don't want only one user account with administrative privileges on Windows 7 because the built-in Administrator account (normally only used in emergencies) is disabled by default. If you're running as Administrator for your daily work and that account gets corrupted, things will be Difficult. It isn't impossible to activate the built-in Administrator to rescue things, but it will require third-party tools and working outside the operating system.
>
> The user account that is for your daily work should be a Standard user, with the extra administrative user (call it something like "CompAdmin" or "Tech" or the like) only there for elevation purposes. Running as a Standard user is best practice for security purposes and will help protect your computer from infection. After you create "CompAdmin", log into it and change your regular user account to Standard. Then log back into your regular account.

Source [Lost administrator account on Windows 7](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/lost-administrator-account-on-windows-7/62a99dcc-b976-4ad1-9ac5-e7bf803eab83)

Comment: If you don't like torrents, there are plenty of alternatives to NeoSmart. Hiren's Boot CD is one. There's also tools to do it included in Kali Linux. You don't even have to use a boot disc, if you slave your drive to another system with the right tools. Any system that can read the drive can take ownership of the Registry and reset/unlock any local account if the user has the knowledge/tools available. The only caveat is that the drive must not be encrypted or, if it is, you must have the encryption key and the host system or LiveCD must have the necessary decryption software.